# Laravel, How to ignore (except) some fields when update model using json and laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

The function below is to update user information, I need to validate if email is not duplicated, also to ignore password if its field left empty, I don't why this function not working!

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

$this->validate($request->all(), [
        'fname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
        'password' => 'same:confirm-password',
        'roles' => 'required'
    ]);


    $input = $request->all()->except(['country_id', 'region_id']);
    if(!empty($input['password'])){ 
        $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
    }else{
        $input = array_except($input,array('password'));    
    }

    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->update($input);
    DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id',$id)->delete();
    $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));
    return response()->json(array('data' => trans('message.success')));
}
```

Comment: Try  `'password' => 'sometimes|same:confirm-password',`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to correct your validation.

You need to change it to

```
$request->validate([
        'fname' => 'required',
        'email' => [
           'required',
           'email',
           Rule::unique('users')->ignore($id),
        ],
        'password' => 'same:confirm-password',
        'roles' => 'required'
    ]);
```

$request->all() returns an array, you need to change it to

```
$input = $request->except(['country_id', 'region_id']);
```

Also I would change the condition to use Laravel's build-in method:

```
if($request->filled('password'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `$request` object not `$request->all()`, that returns an array of the input.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'fname' => 'required',
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($id),
    ],
    'password' => 'nullable,confirmed',
    'roles' => 'required'
]);
```

I changed the password rule to check if it exists and if it does, it confirms it matches.

Again, I removed the chained `all()` method

```
$input = $request->except(['country_id', 'region_id']);
if(!empty($input['password'])){ 
    $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
}else{
    $input = array_except($input,array('password'));    
}
```

Remember to use

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

Comment: Could you clarify what doesn't work, the password validation?

Comment: if I removed the validation then it works fine, I can't validate the inputs :(

Comment: I refactored to use Rule

Comment: now this working fine, $this->validate($request, [
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id
]);
   I just wanted to show error message if the email validation is error